# SQL - Count how many itmes in a GROUP also using SUM

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using PDO (still learning) and have the current SQL query. This works perfectly, merging duplicate entries and adding their value. Is there a way I could see how many duplicate entries there were?

```
$SQL = "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) FROM table WHERE Date > :FromDate AND Date < :EndDate GROUP BY Col1";
```

My table looks like this

```
Col1     Col2 
-----  ------
ABC       2
ABA       3
ADD       1
AED       3
ABC       2
ABA       3
ADD       1
AED       3
AED       0
```

At the moment, after I loop through, the result looks like this

```
Col1    Col2    
----    ----    
ABC       4
ABA       6
ADD       2
AED       6
```

But i'd like to get the value of how many times it occured in the DB before it was grouped so i could end up with

```
Col1    Col2    Times Appeared
----    ----    --------------
ABC       4           2
ABA       6           2
ADD       2           2
AED       6           3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `count()` for that. It counts only the records in a group if used with `group by`

```
SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2), count(*) as 'Times appeared'
FROM table 
WHERE Date > :FromDate AND Date < :EndDate 
GROUP BY Col1"
```

Comment: Since you answered first, I'll comment here; `Date BETWEEN :FromDate AND :EndDate`

Comment: It is `date > fromdate` and not `date >= fromdate` and that does not match `between`, right?

Comment: thanks @juergend this helped a lot. I tried to use `BETWEEN` also but it didn't work. Nothing appeared. It's ok though, my main problem is resolved

Answer (score 1):

Add a COUNT, like this:

```
SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2), COUNT(*)
FROM table 
WHERE Date > :FromDate 
  AND Date < :EndDate 
GROUP BY Col1
```

Answer (score 0):

add `COUNT(Col1)` as the last thing selected in your query.  Why would that not work?

So, I don't know why the downvotes.. unless this is a platform difference, but in SQL Server the following code is equivalent

```
DECLARE @temptbl TABLE 
(
    textcol varchar(50),
    numcol int
)

INSERT INTO @temptbl (textcol,numcol) VALUES('test',4)
INSERT INTO @temptbl (textcol,numcol) VALUES('test',3)
INSERT INTO @temptbl (textcol,numcol) VALUES('test',2)
INSERT INTO @temptbl (textcol,numcol) VALUES('test2',1)
INSERT INTO @temptbl (textcol,numcol) VALUES('test2',3)

SELECT textcol,SUM(numcol),COUNT(numcol) FROM @temptbl GROUP BY textcol
SELECT textcol,SUM(numcol),COUNT(*) FROM @temptbl GROUP BY textcol
```

Comment: OP does not want to count col1. OP wants to count duplicates.

Comment: I understand that, but counting col1 would provide the count of col1 items with the same value that contributed to the sum, the same as counting * with the grouping specified, again.. unless this is a difference between MySQL and SQL Server

Comment: Thanks, forgot about SQLFiddle, should have posted one.